# How to scanline in 1D barcode region?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst, scanline

I need to  scanline the region of interest for my image to check that it includes 1D barcode or not. Can anyone help me in how to implement this?Any relevant function ?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I have rectangles for region of interest that is including same orientation of  gradient image. And now i have to check these regions for detecting 1D barcode.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the Computer Vision System Toolbox seems to be what you are looking for.

You can find more about it here:

http://www.mathworks.nl/help/vision/examples/barcode-recognition.html

Comment: Please, do you know how can I see the code for that function vipbarcoderecognition ?